# Looking for the earliest history entry of a product should I join history/product tables or store value in product table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, relational-database

I have a MySQL database with a table for products and a table with the buying/selling history of these products. The buying and selling history of each product is basically tracked in this history table.
I am looking for the most efficient way of creating a list of these products with the earliest transaction data from the history table joined.
At the moment my SQL query selects the products with the earliest history entry like this:

```
SELECT p.*
     , h.transdate
     , h.sale_price 
  FROM products p
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MIN(transdate) transdate
             , product_id 
          FROM history
        GROUP 
            BY product_id
     ) hist_min
  ON hist_min.product_id = p.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN history h
  ON h.product_id = hist_min.product_id 
   AND h.transdate = hist_min.transdate
```

Since this query is used very frequently and potentially with many products I am considering storing the first sale_price directly in the 'products' table. This way I wouldn't need the 2 additional JOINS at all. But this would mean I store redundant data.
For me the most important question is, which of these possibilities is the most efficient one.
I am not sure if I am allowed to ask this additionally, but if there is an even better way I would like to know about it.

**EDIT:** To clarify 'efficient', I am talking about tens of thousands of products with maybe 10 history records each, where I only pick pagewise 20 with a LIMIT statement. To save the original price with the product would be pulling the data straight with the record, while the scanning of dates in the history table for the earliest time and another scan to join the actual row of data would require certainly more resources, even if only for the second table involved. The use of a primary key ID oder an index over product_id and transdate would certainly speed up the second join though.

Comment: I would say, until you run into problems, stick with what you've got.

Comment: What does "efficient" mean? (Answer: Nothing.) Learn principles of info modeling & db design from a textbook. When you know what options and costs there are you can start telling people how you want them traded off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is called 'normalization'. The level of normalization is not a black and white area so I don't think this site is the place to get your answer as it's primarily opinion based.

Check out these links to get started:

[Database Normalization Explained in Simple English](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) (check out the 'See also' section, it describes level of normalization)

Comment: The "simple" link is so vague and wrong that it's useless. No article in the wiki tells you *how to normalize*. And normalization to a NF is not done by moving through lower NFs. One should read and follow a textbook.

Comment: Tbh I didn't read it closely enough and you're totally right. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Nevermind, thought you could do strikethrough. Editing it out is a cop-out so I'll leave it as is.

Comment: Why is editing a cop-out? The protocol is to edit one's post to be as good as possible. (Without invalidating reasonable posted answers.) Whereas comments are ephemeral.

Comment: I chose this answer, because it points out, that normalization is not a black and white area.